# automatic line on every terminal tab open

Tags: linux, terminal

I started getting this weird line every time I open a new terminal tab.

```
3='cd -3'
ruby-2.1.5 ➜  /Volumes/dev_directory
```

It started about a month ago and I've looked in the

```
~/.profile
~/.bashrc
~/.zshrc
```

nothing....

where else can I look for it?

Comment: What shell are you using? If `bash` have you looked at `/etc/bashrc` `/etc/profile`, and the files in `/etc/bash_completion.d`?

Comment: Try `env SHELLOPTS=xtrace /path/to/Terminal`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Or just `$SHELL -x`.

Comment: @n.st. We don't know how that "Terminal" implementation starts the `$SHELL`. It may very well start it as a login shell. In which case, `bash -lx` may be better.

Comment: @n.st, `env SHELLOPTS=xtrace` can also be useful in that it activates `xtrace` also for bash scripts (and on OS/X sh is bash) called from those bashrc files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That output looks a lot like something called `alias` with fewer parameters than intended.
Try running

```
echo | $SHELL -ix | grep alias
```

to find whatever is printing the annoying line, then `grep` for that in your home directory, `/etc`, perhaps `/usr/share`, and wherever else you might have put something that influences your shell.

(As for that command: `-x` prints a trace of all commands that are executed, and `-i` ensures you get a login shell (i.e. your shell's rc and profile files are loaded) even though input is coming from a pipe.)

Comment: yeah, that was it, an alias I've added to sublime text 3... thanks